# If $x^2=10z-34$, $y^2=8x-23$, $z^2=7-6y$, find the integer value of $x+y^2+z^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, substitution

> The following set of equations is given:
> $$\begin{align}
> \ & x^2=10z-34  \\
> \ & y^2=8x-23    \\
> \ & z^2=7-6y  \end{align}\\$$
> It is asked to find the **integer** value of $x+y^2+z^3$.

I have tried finding individual values of $x$, $y$, and $z$ but that leads to a very messy and large equation. When I try substituting values into $x+y^2+z^3$, I keep getting stuck in a loop where each variable substitution leads to the next variable and in the end I'm not able to solve it. Clearly there must be an easier way to solve this question, using simple algebra, but I'm not able to find it.

Any help leading towards the solution will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd solve it without a computer, and assuming that there's at most one solution.

Assume all variables are integers. Note that since $x^2,y^2,z^2\geq0$, $10z\geq34$, so $z\geq4$. Thus, $7-6y\geq16$, so $y\leq -2$. Thus, $8x-23\geq4$, so $x\geq4$.

So, $10z-34\geq16$, and thus $z\geq5$. So $7-6y\geq25$, and thus $y\leq-3$. Thus, $8x-23\geq9$, and so $x\geq4$.

This gives us a solution $(4,-3,5)$.

Comment: I didn't think about using inequalities as a method for solving, thank you

Comment: Yes. I think this is a important point "Assume all variables are integers." Otherwise, we need another proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There is an obvious integer solution
$$
(x,y,z)=(4,-3,5).
$$
Substituting $6y:=7-z^2$ and
$8x:=y^2+23$  the last equation gives
$$
(z-5)f(x)=0
$$
with an irreducible polynomial $f\in \Bbb Z[z]$, which has no real root. Hence the above solution is the only real solution.

Comment: IMHO, we need irreducible, at least over the reals isn't it?Because, the sum of irrational numbers can easily be an integer.

Comment: @lonestudent Yes, in fact one can show that $f(x)$ has no real root. This shows that the integer solution is the only real solution. But there are six more complex solutions.

Comment: Thank you, for confirming.

Comment: Did I understand correct? Do you say, it is possible we can choose $x,y,z\in\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$ such that $(x+y^2+z^3) \in\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: @lonestudent I think the exercise is assuming tacitly that we find the integer value among the *real* solutions. Almost always complex solutions are ignored for this type of homework. Also, it is not exactly clear what is meant by "the" integer value. For example, with $(x,y,z)=(i,i,-\sqrt[3]{i-1})$, the expression $x+y^2+z^3$ is zero, hence an integer.

Comment: Thank you for clarifications.(+)

Answer (score 0):

A numerical approach can be taken this way:

Set $x_0=y_0=z_0=0$

Let $x_{n+1}=\frac{{y_n}^2+23}8$

Let $y_{n+1}=\frac{7-{z_n}^2}6$

Let $z_{n+1}=\frac{{x_n}^2+34}{10}$

The values converge (but very slowly).

I had $x_{23}=3.766577037, y_{23}=-2.663788835, z_{23}=4.813051628$

You can see where it's heading at that point.

Comment: The rate of convergence of this process is pretty slow. You can do quite a bit better with some basic num analysis techniques.

Comment: @DonThousand Yes, I agree. I've edited the answer to include the fact that convergence is slow.